# matchcollection with distinct values vb.net

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a matchCollection

> Dim matchList As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(...)

that has all links from a certain site. Now I want to distinct all that links in another MatchCollection or array variable. So every link must be appears only once.

Any idea?

I am using vb.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
' Gets all the matches.
Dim LinkMatches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(...)
Dim LinkList As New List(Of String)

' Gets the matches values and assign them to a list.
 For Each Match As Match In LinkMatches
     LinkList.Add(Match.Value)
 Next

 ' Using the Distinct function to eliminate duplicates links.
 LinkList = LinkList.Distinct.ToList
```

Comment: thank you for the solution you provided. I tried it but the distinct doesn't work. I am getting the same List.Count number before and after the last command

Comment: Probably because there are no duplicates items produced by the Regex. Are you sure there are duplicates items? And by duplicates, I mean, the exact same thing...

Comment: yes, I am sure. The same links are returned about 3 times for some of them

Comment: Wierd...Any way, I tested this code with a simple example and it did the work. Can you provide an example of your results? Maybe show some links.

Comment: Oh, my fault! Your code is fine, thank you! I did a mistake in another part of the code :)